# Как правильно работать с ROW_NUMBER()?

Tags: mysql, sql

подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать независимую нумерацию.

У меня есть таблица `task`, допустим с 3 полями: `id, name, task_id`

Всего в таблице хранится 10 заданий, 3 из которых - мои.

На определённой странице вывожу только свои задания, но мне нужно узнать их номер в списке всех заданий.

Пример:

```
id, name, task_id
1   name1 8
2   name2 85
3   name3 6
4   name4 74
5   name5 15
6   name6 2
7   name7 1
```

Мои задания - 1, 4, 7.

Значит при правильном запросе у меня должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
num, id, name,  task_id
4     1  name1  74
2     4  name4  85
7     7  name7  1
```

ORDER BY - task_id DESC

**MySQL (ver. 8.0.20)**

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему в результате у Вас поменялись `task_id` у задач, было 8, 74, 1 стало 4, 2, 7

Comment: @namerek исправил, случайно не туда записал

Comment: @yitzhak-khabinsky Добавил версию в вопрос

Comment: Какие данные должно содержать поле `num` в результате?

Comment: @namerek Там должен быть порядковый номер задания из списка всех заданий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нумеруем все, затем выбираем нужные:

```
SELECT num, id, name, task_id
FROM(
  SELECT id, name, task_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY task_id desc) AS num
  FROM task
) T
WHERE id IN (1, 4, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

До сих пор не ясно, как вы пришли к желаемому результату.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad87aeff1de0d55ae4610566fa147779)

> SQLfiddle

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(30), task_id INT);
INSERT tbl (id, name, task_id)
VALUES
(1, 'name1' ,8 ),
(2, 'name2' ,85),
(3, 'name3' ,6 ),
(4, 'name4' ,74),
(5, 'name5' ,15),
(6, 'name6' ,2 ),
(7, 'name7' ,1 );
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS num
FROM tbl
WHERE id IN (1, 4, 7);
```

> результат

```
+----+-------+---------+-----+
| id | name  | task_id | num |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
|  1 | name1 |       8 |   1 |
|  4 | name4 |      74 |   2 |
|  7 | name7 |       1 |   3 |
+----+-------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Из-за `WHERE id IN (1, 4, 7);` ROW_NUMBER() нумерует только из выборки этих трёх записей, мне же надо узнать их номер из ВСЕХ записей в таблице

Comment: Разве это не столбец id? он уже имеет глобальный  порядковый номер.

Comment: да, но какая разница, если ORDER BY - task_id DESC, и task_id будет очень часто меняться. И вот нужно узнать именно по task_id какой у записи порядковый номер